# Adding Bulk Collections into procedure in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure and it is used for inserting a table. It takes another table's datas and join them together then inserting new table.
In this procedure I want to use bulk collections for making these operations more faster. I am challenging in syntax and where to use these bulk collections.
Does anybody help or share ideas with me?
I am adding my database scripts below, thank you from now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FCBSADM.extract_monthly_data(pid_billdate DATE) is

v_cnt   NUMBER;
          
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table gpu';
                  
   v_cnt := 0;
   
   FOR REC in (SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE     abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
          AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id  
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate)
    loop 
      
      INSERT INTO GPU
         SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id 
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1, 
                bill_acct ba2, 
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id 
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID 
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id  
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id 
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT' 
                AND abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = rec.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+);                    
                    

      v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;

      IF MOD (v_cnt, 1000) = 0
      THEN
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
      COMMIT;   
    end loop;
    COMMIT;

end;
```

/

This is the last version of it. Errors are gone but no record is coming to GPU table and I am working on it.

```
        create or replace procedure extract_monthly_data(pid_billdate DATE) is
v_cnt      NUMBER;
TYPE prod_ids_t IS TABLE OF apld_bill_rt.intl_prod_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;  
l_prod_ids   prod_ids_t;  
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table gpu';
                  
   v_cnt := 0;
   
   SELECT DISTINCT abr.intl_prod_id, ab.bill_date BULK COLLECT INTO l_prod_ids
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE     abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 1000 
          AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          ORDER BY bill_date;
    
    FOR indx IN 1 .. l_prod_ids.COUNT
    loop  
      INSERT INTO GPU
      SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
            AB.BILL_NO,
            AB.INV_ID,
            AB.BILL_DATE,
            ba2.bill_acct_id,
            ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
            AB.DUE_DATE,
            PG.CMPG_ID,
            ABR.NET_AMT,
            AB.DUE_AMT,
            P.PROD_NUM,
            pds.DST_ID,
            ABR.DESCR,
            p.intl_prod_id 
       FROM apld_bill_rt abr
            JOIN acct_bill ab ON AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID 
            JOIN FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds ON 
            JOIN bill_acct_prod bap ON bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id 

                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id 
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
            JOIN prod p ON bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
            JOIN bill_acct ba1 ON ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id 
            JOIN bill_acct ba2 ON ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id 
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_cmpg pg ON p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id
            WHERE ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT' 
            AND abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
            AND ABR.intl_prod_id =ANY (
              SELECT intl_prod_id 
              FROM apld_bill_rt abr
                JOIN acct_bill ab ON abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
              WHERE abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 1000 
                AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
              );                    

      v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;

      IF MOD (v_cnt, 1000) = 0
      THEN
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
  
    end loop;
    COMMIT;

end;
```

This is the table that I want to insert into. The procedure compiled successfully but doesnt insert any record.

```
    create table GPU
(
  acct_bill_id        NUMBER(16),
  bill_no             VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  inv_id              VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  bill_date           DATE,
  bill_acct_id        NUMBER(38),
  parent_bill_acct_id NUMBER(38),
  due_date            DATE,
  cmpg_id             NUMBER,
  net_amt             NUMBER(16,2),
  due_amt             NUMBER(16,2),
  prod_num            VARCHAR2(32 CHAR),
  dst_id              NUMBER(22) not null,
  descr               VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  intl_prod_id        NUMBER(14) not null
);
```

Comment: you don't need to use neither a loop , nor a bulk collect. It could be written as a simple sql statement

Comment: @RobertoHernandez this will be used for a telecommunication company. So in that query contains about 200.000 records and more. This is the reason why I have use more fast option for not facing any congestion while executing billing&charging modules.

Comment: @burakzbc, I will provide you the two options, but the procedure without loop will be faster

Comment: @RobertoHernandez what about bulk collections with no loop and inside of a  procedure which belongs to a package?

Comment: what table belongs the column `intl_prod_id` ?

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez intl_prod_id is a column of apld_bill_rt table which we are storing invoice details and "abr" is alias of it.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I edited question with the table which I want to insert into. The procedure compiled well no, errors. However, I cant see any records in GPU table. Can you look at that :/

Comment: @burakzbc, first delete the answer you have below, second run the select distinct manually and see how many distinct ids you recovered. if you don't insert any row, either you don't have ids, or you don't have any of those ids which match the join condition in the insert / select. Let me tell you **again** that you are using the wrong approach. Use option 1 is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not need any `loop` or `bulk collect`, but it is up to you. The reason is that you have all the values in the `select distinct` , and you are joining this dataset against the main query. It would be much better use a simple insert inside the procedure.

*By the way, you should try to avoid this old syntax and start using normal SQL ANSI which is much easier to understand and maintain.*

**Option 1**

Without cursor, nor bulk collect, just a  simple insert select

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FCBSADM.extract_monthly_data( pid_billdate DATE) is
             
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table gpu';
                  
   -- direct path is faster here, as you are truncating the table before
   
   INSERT /*+append */ INTO GPU
   with x as ( SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE     abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
          AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id  
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate
    )
    SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id 
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1, 
                bill_acct ba2, 
                prod_cmpg pg, 
                x
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id 
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID 
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id  
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id 
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT' 
                AND abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = x.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+);                    
                    
       COMMIT;   
end;
```

**Option 2**

If you want to use bulk collect, which I don't recommend it here, one option might be. *Check for any syntax error, as I did not have any way to replicate the code*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FCBSADM.extract_monthly_data(pid_billdate DATE) is
v_cnt      NUMBER;
TYPE prod_ids_t IS TABLE OF apld_bill_rt.intl_prod_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; -- whatever the table is 
l_prod_ids   prod_ids_t;  
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table gpu';
                  
   v_cnt := 0;
   
   SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id BULK COLLECT INTO l_prod_ids
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE     abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
          AND abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id  
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate);
    
    FOR indx IN 1 .. l_prod_ids.COUNT
    loop  
      INSERT INTO GPU
         SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id 
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1, 
                bill_acct ba2, 
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id 
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID 
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id  
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id 
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT' 
                AND abr.cdate > SYSDATE - 5
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx)
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+);                    

      v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;

      IF MOD (v_cnt, 1000) = 0
      THEN
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
  
    end loop;
    COMMIT;

end;
```

Comment: @burakzbc , any feedback ??

Comment: I am checking and testing I'll let you know, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I added some errors as an answer can you look at below?

Comment: @burakzbc , you should rethink the whole approach. In the bulk collect, you need to run the query with the joins each time for any record in the loop. That is a waste of time, mostly when it is not necessary

Comment: Compilation errors for PROCEDURE FCBSADM.EXTRACT_MONTHLY_DATA

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "L_EMPLOYEE_IDS": invalid identifier
Line: 52
Text: AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_employee_ids(indx)

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 22
Text: INSERT INTO GPU

Comment: typo error. It is l_prod_ids ( not l_employee_ids ). Try again

Comment: @burakzbc, remove your answer below, and include the new information in the question itself.

Comment: I edited question and added last version of it. I build it with joins but now I am getting this error :(   :Compilation errors for PROCEDURE FCBSADM.EXTRACT_MONTHLY_DATA

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
Line: 40
Text: JOIN bill_acct_prod bap ON bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 22
Text: INSERT INTO GPU

Error: Hint: Parameter 'pid_billdate' is declared but never used in 'extract_monthly_data'
Line: 1
Text: create or replace procedure extract_monthly_data(pid_billdate DATE) is

Comment: `JOIN FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds ON` is missing the condition

Comment: How can I remove loop but still use the Bulk collections? I know it is better for your solution but my manager insisted on bulk collection unfortunately :(

Comment: bulk collection only works in loops. your case is not for a bulk or a loop.. It is clearly an insert select. Your manager should be managing, not telling you how to develop